# VBA for Pivot Table with query table as data source

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table that has a connection to a query in the workbook to serve as the data source. When I try to write the following VBA code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Income").Calculation = xlNormal,
```

I get runtime error:

> '1004' - unable to get the pivotfields property of the pivottable class.

Is this because I have an error in my code or because I'm not using a regular data source?

Comment: Validate pivot table name "PivotTable1" and pivot field name "Sum of Income"

Answer (score 0):

It would seem your code isn't able to reach the `.Calcuation` propertie. Try to use a macro recorder to check if your names are valid when you use this code.

My guess is that "Sum of Income" is the source of this error in your case.

Comment: Thanks! I used the macro recorder and saw that ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Measures].[Sum of Income]") was the correct code.

Comment: Glad I helped you :)